# Propositional Logic Formula Graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, graph-theory, propositional-calculus

If you take a propositional logic formula with you can construct a graph in a straightforward manner: each connective is a node and there is an edge between two nodes iff the nodes share a variable.

My question is how do you call this graph. I would call it a structural graph but it doesn't sound right.

Comment: Are you referring to what is often called the parse graph of the formula?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi: Do you mean the Abstract Syntax Tree that you get by parsing a formula? Nope. This is much more related to the Boolean circuit that corresponds to a propositional formula.

Comment: I meant graph, not tree, because you can share common subexpressions and it's often advantageous.